# Cannot access Civi dashboard

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

Earlier I updated several Wordpress plugins. One of those updates broke my access to Wordpress admin. So, I restored the backup I made prior to updating the plugins. After the restore I still cannot access the Civi dashboard.

When I try, I get this:

[image]

Note, I also cannot access my Wordpress Network dashboard. WHen I try I get this:

[image]

I have a subsite and from the subsite's dashboard, I can access the Civi dashboard, but I get the same error when I try to access the network dashboard.

What do I need to do to regain access to the Civi dashboard?

I'm using Wordpress 4.9.9 and CiviCRM 5.4.1.